# Is it possible to receive a Stripe Webhook for a payment event before I can hit my servers controller to finish processing?

Tags: stripe-payments

In my app, on the client side, I'm calling Stripe's "confirmCardPayment()" to finish the purchase. When the result comes back I take the result, if successful, and then call my server controller to finish the processing (DB entry).

**QUESTION** - Would it be possible to confirm the payment on the client side with Stripe and then receive the Stripe Webhook on the server side before I have time to post back to the controller to finish the payment processing? Or put another way, is the Webhook sent immediately or does it wait for some time before it's sent to the endpoint?

Answer (score -1):

Stripe does not guarantee delivery of events in the order in which they are generated. You can read about it in more detail here : https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/best-practices#event-ordering

You would want to always rely on the webhook to update your database or execute business logic as relying on requests triggered from the browser isn't reliable. E.g.  Your customer could close the browser after the payment is authorised but before you are able to post to your server to update your database.

Comment: My question isn't in regards to the order Webhooks are generated and sent. My question asked if it was possible to receive the Webhook (ex. payment_intent.succeeded) before the client has time to call my server to update my DB, after I've called 'confirmCardPayment' on the client side to create the charge.

Comment: Yes, it is possible for you to receive the Webhook before the client has time to call your server to update your DB.

Comment: ok, if that's the case, which I assume it is, then I could potentially end up with a scenario where I will be attempting to insert a row (Payment) into a DB where it already exists. Ex. Before the client has a chance to get to my server and create a new "Payment" entity, the webhook is called, received by my server and then the webhook creates the "Payment" entity with all the details of the charge (ex. card, exp month, exp year, amount charged, etc, etc). It then saves it. Con't...

Comment: A split second later, the client's post to the server is received and tried to do the same thing (create the Payment entity, only to error out when it's saved, because it already exists. How do I handle this scenario? Do I just error out on the DB save call, when trying to insert a duplicate row (PaymentIntentId) in the DB?

Comment: Think of my scenario like a dating app, where the customer is purchasing "super like" credits (10, 20, 50, 100, etc). They make the purchase, the card is charged and then I want to save an entry in the Payment table.